# How can I write a message onto the same file that creates it with flat-file PHP s

Tags: php, html, flat-file

First of all this is not my code, I just need it changed a little.

I need to know how to write messages onto the same file where the user posts the message.

Here is one page where the user can post their message:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form to Flat File</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="sendinfo.php" method="get">
Your Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="name"><br />
Your Message:<br />
<textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send Info">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the other that writes the message onto a PHP file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form to Flat File</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include('config.php');
$user = $_GET["name"]; 
$message = $_GET["message"];
print("<b>Thank You!</b><br />Your information has been added! You can see it by <a href=savedinfo.php>Clicking Here</a>");
$out = fopen("savedinfo.php", "a"); 
if (!$out) { 
print("Could not append to file"); 
exit; 
} 
fputs ($out,implode,("\n")); 
fwrite($out,"<b>$user</b><br />$message<br /><br />");
fclose($out);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Pretty much I just want everything on one page, I got close to doing that but it won't let me write onto the same page. I'm sure it's possible I'm just nowhere near experienced enough. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to put content of both files in a single file, but execute the content of the second file only if form has been submitted.

First of all, change the form's method value to POST and replace all references to **$_GET** with **$_POST**

Then create a single file containing

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form to Flat File</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// here put content of the file that stores form values in a file
// just remove all html code and leave only PHP code
}


?>

// here put content of the file that displays the form
// just remove HTML, HEAD and BODY tags first

</body>
</html>
```